# Does Docker image supporting Nvidia gpu on a cpu machine

Tags: docker, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, pytorch

I want to run a deep neural network on a Docker container. I can use TensorFlow or PyTorch or CNTK images available publicly on Docker Hub that support a GPU. And I can get an NVIDA GPU in the cloud.

What happens when I run those GPU-based containers on my PC that does not have a GPU (or an Intel GPU)? Will the Docker container based on NVIDIA GPU gracefully run on my a CPU (albeit slower)?

It would be great if I could develop on locally without a GPU and scale up with GPU when I am ready to run at scale.

Will this work? Thoughts?

Comment: In addition to the answer given below, I want to add that you have to manually decide on which device your data goes if you use PyTorch. Specifying precisely what you are using in the end will help your chances of  a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If Tensorflow does not find a GPU it will just use the CPU only so this should work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow has an option for allowing soft placement, which means that if the device doesn't exist, it automatically chooses an existing and supported device to run the operations. Quoting from the documentation about [Using GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu) in tensorflow,

> If you would like TensorFlow to automatically choose an existing and
>   supported device to run the operations in case the specified one
>   doesn't exist, you can set allow_soft_placement to True in the
>   configuration option when creating the session.
>
> ```
> # Creates a graph.
> with tf.device('/device:GPU:2'):
>   a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
>   b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
>   c = tf.matmul(a, b)
> # Creates a session with allow_soft_placement and log_device_placement set
> # to True.
> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
>       allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True))
> # Runs the op.
> print(sess.run(c))
> ```